# How to create a Java object in my Robot test

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible to create an java object in my robot test? I import it like the following:

```
Library     my.robot.car

Get mile
    ${carObject}    car volvo 2 
    ${resp}=    Call Method    ${carObject} GetMiles ${today}
    [Return]    ${resp}
```

So i want to create the Car object in the test, then call the method getMiles. But i am getting the error `'Library my.robot.car expected 2 arguments, got 0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are seeing comes from the library initialization. You probably have a constructor method in `my.robot.car`, which expects two arguments. You either have to provide the arguments in the line where you take library into use, or create a zero-arg constructor for the library.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the java keyword is car. You forgot the double space in the call for car

```
Library     my.robot.car

Get mile
    ${carObject}    car  volvo  2 
    ${resp}=    Call Method    ${carObject}  GetMiles  ${today}
    [Return]    ${resp}
```